# Bind DoubleUpDown Value after Minimum and Maximum

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-extended-toolkit

I have a `UserControl` with a `ListBox` and a `DoubleUpDown`. When I select the item in the `ListBox` I want to set the `Minimum`, `Maximum` and the `Value` of the `DoubleUpDown` so the user can change the `Value` not from predefined range, but in some range around the given value. I use this code:

```
<extToolkit:DoubleUpDown Increment="0.1" Value="{Binding SelectedItem.MyValue, ElementName=listBox1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={conv:CheckValue}}" FormatString="0.0">
    <extToolkit:DoubleUpDown.Maximum>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{conv:CorMaximum}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem.MyValue" ElementName="listBox1" />
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem.MaxDif" ElementName="listBox1" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </extToolkit:DoubleUpDown.Maximum>
    <extToolkit:DoubleUpDown.Minimum>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{conv:CorMinimum}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem.MyValue" ElementName="listBox1" />
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem.MaxDif" ElementName="listBox1" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </extToolkit:DoubleUpDown.Minimum>
</extToolkit:DoubleUpDown>
```

The problem is that this code first set the `Value` and after that set the `Minimum` and `Maximum` so if I have this values:

```
Name | MyValue | MaxDif
-----------------------
 One |    6    |   2
 Two |    1    |   1
```

The range for *One* is 4..8 and the range for *Two* is 0..2. If I first select *One* and then *Two* it looks like the `Two.MyVal = 4`, because the value is inserted when the range from *One* is still active.

How to change the code to first set the `Minimum` and `Maximum` and after that set the `Value`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if that is really the case, but from my observation the order in which the properties are set in XAML determines how they are initialized/assigned. Try binding the Value **after** Max/Min like e.g.: `<extToolkit:DoubleUpDown.Value><Binding ...`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just hope that this really works 100% of time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Official Design Recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property) state

> Allow properties to be set in any order even if this results in a temporary invalid state of the object

Which basically means when designing your own control, make sure to omit sanity checks until initialization is complete (until `IsInitialized` is `true` and the `Initialized` event is fired).

Apparently the `DoubleUpDown` was not designed with your exact problem in mind and enforces Min/Max boundaries before initialization is complete.

*Edit: The public source code of [this particular control](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/6dc73683a77ab62f9bfaf6dd8cc2587f1ebfd11b/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/Primitives/UpDownBase.cs#L440) seems to take `IsInitialized` into account so the problem you are having shouldn't actually occur.*

While it is not explicitly stated in any documentation I was able to find, the Xaml Parser sets an objects properties in the order they are encountered.

---

Possible Solution:

You should be able to work around this problem by setting the `Value` property last.